# SUM PRODUCT with DATE and COLUMN functions not working - Why not?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having a problem with the SUMPRODUCT function. I have found a less than ideal work around and would like to see if someone could explain why my ideal formula doesn't work. Below is simplified view of my spreadsheet:

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]

The first table tabCheckout is the list of books I have checked out and the qty (I really like Gone with the wind). (no formulas)

The second table tabBooks is my inventory. (no formulas)

Row 5 is the day of the month 1-31 (no formulas)

Row 6 is where the problem occurs. It should show me the available qty for each day of the month.

Here is the formula that works fine in cell C6:

```
=INDEX(tabBooks,MATCH($B6,tabBooks[Book],0),2)-SUMPRODUCT((tabCheckout[Checkout]<=DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,C5))*(tabCheckout[Checkin]>=DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,C5+1))*(tabCheckout[Book]=$B6)*(tabCheckout[Qty]))
```

My goal was to replace the reference to C5 in the formula with:

```
OFFSET(startDate,0,COLUMN()-COLUMN(startDate))
```

Where startDate = C5. I tried that in cell E6, and it returns a #VALUE! error (hidden by IFERROR). I took out the whole DATE function and put it in cell E7 and it works fine.

Cell E6 formula:

```
=INDEX(tabBooks,MATCH($B6,tabBooks[Book],0),2)-SUMPRODUCT((tabCheckout[Checkout]<=DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,OFFSET(startDate,0,COLUMN()-COLUMN(startDate))))*(tabCheckout[Checkin]>=DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,E5+1))*(tabCheckout[Book]=$B6)*(tabCheckout[Qty]))
```

Cell E7 formula:

```
=DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,OFFSET(startDate,0,COLUMN()-COLUMN(startDate)))
```

Instead of using the OFFSET function, I was desperate and tried the INDIRECT function in cell G6:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(tabBooks,MATCH($B6,tabBooks[Book],0),2)-SUMPRODUCT((tabCheckout[Checkout]<=DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,INDIRECT("F" & COLUMN()-COLUMN(startDate)+1)))*(tabCheckout[Checkin]>=DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,G5+1))*(tabCheckout[Book]=$B6)*(tabCheckout[Qty])),"")
```

I got really, really desperate and tried the DATEVALUE function:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(tabBooks,MATCH($B6,tabBooks[Book],0),2)-SUMPRODUCT((tabCheckout[Checkout]<=DATEVALUE(thisMonth & "/" & OFFSET(startDate,0, COLUMN()-COLUMN(startDate),1,1) & "/" & thisYear))*(tabCheckout[Checkin]>=DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,J5+1))*(tabCheckout[Book]=$B6)*(tabCheckout[Qty])),"")
```

It seems that the SUMPRODUCT function in combination with any DATE* function that uses some form of COLUMN() or ROW() doesn't work. In my real spreadsheet, each week starts with a named range that I then want to OFFSET from using the COLUMN function. I have never seen Excel return a valid value in one cell but won't if you merge the formulas. That's how I usually build up complicated formulas.

Any help as to why the combination of SUMPRODUCT > DATE* > COLUMN() doesn't work would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to replace the reference to C5 at all? When dragged to the right, the part DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,C5) will naturally become DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,D5), DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,E5), etc. Is that not what you want? If not, what should this part be for successive formulas?

Comment: Dragging will also update table references, but you can copy `C6` and paste it to `D6:...`, or use ugly absolute table references like `tabBooks[[Book]:[Book]]`

Comment: Not really sure with your complexity, but the question why `OFFSET` works different whether in array context or not is answered as follows. `OFFSET` returns a cell reference like `X123`. In normal context this reference will be evaluated as it is and returns the content of this cell. In array context the returned reference will be evaluated like `{X123}` which results in #VALUE because of the volatile behavior of `OFFSET`. We have to use the `N()` function to repair this. `SUMPRODUCT((tabCheckout[Checkout]<=DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,N(OFFSET(startDate,0,COLUMN()-COLUMN(startDate)))))*...)`

Comment: @user3964075 I don't see any table references in there which are relative?

Comment: The use of the unqualified COLUMN() is in any case not a very rigorous choice. Much better is to use COLUMNS in such cases: http://excelxor.com/2014/08/25/row-vs-rows-for-consecutive-integer-generation/

Comment: @XOR LX if you drag the formula to the right `tabBooks[Book]` becomes `tabBooks[Qty Owned]` and so on (at least in Excel 2010)

Comment: @user3964075 Hmmm. I have Excel 2010 and they remain as they are when dragged to the right. Perhaps it's some setting change?

Comment: @XOR LX according to this MS article [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-a547e45e-3589-4417-b611-abb7e5d3f912)  (_Moving, copying, and filling structured references_ paragraph), the default behaviour is to change column specifiers. I do not know any setting to disable it.

Comment: @user3964075 Ahhh! How strange! There is a difference between copying and filling! Apologies - I personally never use the fill handle, always preferring to copy and paste. Thanks for the link - learnt something new! (And it's also reassured me that my choice to never use table names in formulas was a good one!!)

Comment: The actual list of month days is set up in a normal month view with seven columns across and multiple rows. If I replace C5 with the OFFSET / COLUMN combination, I can copy and paste the formulas and all will be well. That being said, AXEL RICHTER answered the question and solved the problem (I tested it with both INDIRECT and the OFFSET functions). If you want to Add that as an answer instead of a comment, I'll be glad to mark it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: I'm not sure whether the complexity of those formulas are really necessary. Thats why my answer is not really the complete answer to this question. But the question contains the question "Why `OFFSET` works different whether in array context or not?" as a part. The answer to this part of the question is:

`SUMPRODUCT` takes all of it's arguments in array context. That is, they will be evaluated as if they were within an array formula.

`OFFSET`and `INDIRECT` have volatile behavior. That is, all changes of the worksheet, not only changes of the arguments of `OFFSET`and `INDIRECT`, will lead to a recalculation of `OFFSET`and `INDIRECT` formulas. Within array context this behavior leads to a kind of endless loop, which leads to the `#VALUE` error, except we stop this by using the results of `OFFSET`and `INDIRECT` as arguments for a non volatile function.

In other words:
`OFFSET` returns a cell reference like `X123`. In normal context this reference will be evaluated as it is and returns the content of this cell. In array context the returned reference will be evaluated like `{X123}` which results in `#VALUE` because of the volatile behavior of `OFFSET`. We have to use the results of `OFFSET` as arguments for a non volatile function to repair this. In this case the `N()` function offers because we need numbers from `OFFSET`.

```
...SUMPRODUCT((tabCheckout[Checkout]<=DATE(thisYear,thisMonth,N(OFFSET(startDate,0‌​,COLUMN()-COLUMN(startDate)))))*...)
```

In other cases maybe `T()` has to be used, because we need text.